# Remove or Disable MBR from old C:\ Drive

Tags: hard-drive, mbr, rootkit

Using a USB to Sata connection from an old XP box, is it possible to remove/disable the MBR\boot sector on a drive pulled from a Win7 box?

C: - I can see the drive and folders and such on my XP box, thru the usb, but it tries to boot.
There is a rootkit virus in the MBR, so i would like remove or disable the MBR.

Doing this on XP(old machine i can screw up) don't want to connect that C: to the Win 7 and have it re install the virus, if thats possible.

I got a new hard drive for Win 7, so its totally clean.

Comment: Can't you just change the boot priority in the BIOS?

Comment: The BIO does not see it thru the USB connection. XP is already loaded, and the hard just starts running like its trying to boot when i connect it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things:

- Disconnect the XP disk, while keeping the infected Win7 disk plugged to the computer, boot the computer with a Win7 DVD, and through a command line use fixmbr to overwrite the infected MBR on that disk with a clean one;
- Or delete every single partition from the infected hard drive and create a new one (but back up first as you will lose all data in the process).

Comment: Sparked another idea, I guess i could copy all the data and burn it to dvd on my XP box, then wipe C. Then AV scan the DVD. Did not think of that.